# Hibernate ManyToMany mapping updating the non owning side

Tags: java, hibernate

My app has 2 java pojo classes linked via ManyToMany relationship `User` & `Season`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_season", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "season_id") })
    private Set<Season> followingSeason;

  Set<Season> getSeasonsWhichTheUserFollows(){
    return this.followingSeason;
  }

}
```

`Season` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "season")
public class Season implements Serializable{

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followingSeason", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> user;

}
```

When a user unfollows a season `unfollowedSeason` object I remove it from the set of season which the user follows.

```
Set<Season> seasonSet = user.getSeasonsWhichTheUserFollows();
seasonSet.remove(unfollowedSeason);
user.setFollowingSeason(seasonSet );
this.userService.update(user);
```

well this removes the entry from the `user_season` bridge table, everything is fine. But at the same time I also want to update some fields of the Season entity in the db for an instance decrementing the count of users following by 1. Is there a way I can do that within the same call? Or do I have to run a separate query to update the season entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i got that right, but why can't you just put something in there like `unfollowedSeason.setCount(unfollowedSeason.getCount() +1 )` and then just update the season?

**EDIT AFTER DISCUSSION IN COMMENTS:**
What you want to do is not possible because
you can't do a update and a remove in the same SQL Statement(as over9k stated)

Comment: I am just trying to avoid 2 db calls in a method. Anyway I am updating the user so was thinking may be any way to update the season at the same time.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't think that's possible. Your seasons are in a different table, and as far as i know you can't update contents of different tables in one call. Am i wrong?

Comment: Imagine that. How would you do that in one **SQL** statement? You wouldn`t, becasue mixing delete and update is impossible.